# What this Url ending means .....&123?

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla

Hey I am having some issues while using Nggalley plugin for wordpress

the plugin makes use of a JW player and JW player needs an XML
- so it requests link like this http://nextgen-gallery.com/index.php?callback=imagerotator&gid=1&**149**
The lay &xxx really creaps me out couse I am using it for joomla and joomla doesn't like this 
I am assuming that this has to do with wordpress but still unsure.

what does this ending of URL really mean?

PS. I would never ever use wordpress plugin in joomla but my client uses and I have to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the numbers different on each page refresh? If so, my guess is that it is to prevent caching (the browser sees the URL as a different URL with the random number appended to the end.)

Comment: +1 what I was typing. Could be a serial-number-based cachebreaker too, updated on each database change.

Comment: Yes it was a cache avoid work around of JW imagerotator, but the joomla was preventing it from being executed, so I just preg_replaced the request Url in joomla, thanks god don't have to debug this mess again =)